# [Solved]How specify OpenCV version in cv_bridge

Tags: ros-melodic, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I'm in ROS Melodic and I'm working with OpenCV 4.5.3 for xfeatures2d. At the end of catkin_make, i have this warnings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.5.3, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
```

I've seen many questions for this warnings, that suggest to clone cv_bridge from source code. But I don't understand I specify OpenCV version in my cv_bridge. I've tried to change CMakeFile of cv_bridge like this:

find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED -> find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED

but can't build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391854/%5Bsolved%5Dhow-specify-opencv-version-in-cv_bridge/) by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution in [Github](https://github.com/fizyr-forks/vision_opencv/tree/opencv4):

In catkin_ws/src:

```
git clone https://github.com/fizyr-forks/vision_opencv/tree/opencv4
cd vision_opencv
git checkout opencv4
```

---

Originally posted by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-29**:
Thank you for sharing